# Where is the famous excellent documentation of Satchless?

Tags: django, satchless

It's not a joke. I'm trying to see if I'm missing something. In the [official documentation](http://docs.satchless.com/en/latest/index.html), I see only a description and the claim that the framework is well-documented. I wonder where is this excellent documentation?

I need to write a simple demo e-shop with a simple list of products and integration with *ipayment.de*. The list, I can do easily. But where do I read on how to integrate the ipayment form with the shop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [a `doc/` directory in the git repository](https://github.com/mirumee/satchless/blob/master/doc/), which contains what looks like the source files for `docs.satchless.com`. You can `cd` into the `doc/` directory and run `make` (you'll probably need to install [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/)) to generate the HTML docs yourself.

It looks like, in addition to the index page you linked to, there is a file `product.rst`, which is amazingly not linked from `index.rst` (and thus `product.html` is not linked  from `index.html`):

> http://docs.satchless.com/en/latest/product.html

If that doesn't fulfil "well-documented", perhaps they mean it *will* be so? ;)

Comment: and even this link is dead :)

Comment: Crikey... well, if anyone is still desperate to use a project that's fallen so far off the map, you can access the docs using the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20121125095132/http://docs.satchless.com/en/latest/product.html